# Is it possible to achieve the actual binary numbers from a bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

My professor kind of "challenged me" to create an application that draws pixel by pixel an image converted in Bitmap, where it's data is saved in some sort of binary that I can't wrap my head around.

Here's the example given to me:

```
const byte image[]={
B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,
B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,
B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,
B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,
B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,B00000000,
ect ect ect
```

Now, if the byte data type saves numbers that go from 0 to 255, how is this possible? In the sample code that I was given, there is also the use of "Word" data type but in my IDE it seems like it doesn't exist.

I already wrote the code that converts any image given in input into a bitmap:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //Path is image location 
Byte[] bindata = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
fs.Read(bindata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
Bitmap bmp;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bindata))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp; //For now, I just display the converted image on screen
```

Now I suppose that the next step is to draw the image byte per byte, but I can't get my head around this binary thing and the word data type.. Any kind of help is appreciated :)

Comment: your code is getting a byte array from a filestream and then making a bitmap out of it.  What are you trying to do?  Convert the const byte image[]... to a bitmap?  And where do you see 'word' datatype?

Comment: You professor "challenged you", not us. We will not do your homework.

Comment: *"I can't get my head around this binary thing"* -- so do some research. Find out what bits and bytes and words etc. actually are. This should've been taught to you in class, but who knows what they teach in schools these days. However that shouldn't be necessary, as it's all trivial.

Comment: @chris-crush-code Yes, I'm trying to convert it into a bitmap. The Word datatype is in some other code that's given to me, but I did not add it completely into context as I believe I am able to find a way around it. The thing I can't understand is the byte data type containing binary, as when I try to write a line to the console that says for example bindata[1], the output is a regular int number

Comment: Is he asking you to manually decode a bitmap file?  If so, this may be helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format . But that seems kind of advanced for the programming level you seem to be at.  Perhaps you need clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: You'll need at least the width and height of the image...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to draw a bitmap pixel at a time, you can do something like this:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(10, 10);
b.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
b.SetPixel(1, 3, Color.Red);
pictureBox1.Image = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy your bytes to the Bitmap's memory buffer itself.

```
BitmapData bufferData = buffer.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    bufferData.SetPixel(x, y, CELL_DEAD);

buffer.UnlockBits(bufferData);

//////////

public static unsafe void SetPixel(BitmapData data, int x, int y, byte pixel)
{
  *((byte*)data.Scan0 + y * data.Stride + x) = pixel;
}
```

I've used it as *unsafe* but you can play your magic with IntPtr. Of course, you must play your own with width-height synchronization.

UPD: set `PixelFormat` with care. `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` is what you need if your colors are in default 256-color palette or you want to define your own palette.

Comment: `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` is most likely *not* the correct `PixelFormat`, as that involves palettes, and is rarely used.

Comment: It depends on task. If we using the default 256-color palette (as I done when writing this for my own purposes) it's ok. Also TS used 8bpp (1 byte per pixel), so this is the only format he can use without color conversion.

Comment: I'd just write the byte array to disk and use a tool like TiledGGD to check how to make an image out of it...